# C++ Cannot convert argument 1 from 'KeyValue<K,V> *' to 'const T &'

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am having issues with a Hash Table that I am trying to build. It is supposed to have an array of Linked List, whenever I call the insertLast function I built for it i get a conversion error:

Cannot convert argument 1 from 'KeyValue *' to 'const T &'.

From what I've seen while trying to solve this problem something is being declared incorrectly but I can't identify where the problem is or if that is even correct. Any help is greatly appreciated. This is for a homework assignment so I'd ask that you just help me identify this one problem, if anything else breaks along the way I'd rather find that out myself.

```
//hash table class
template <typename K, typename V>
class HashTable
{
    friend class LinkedList<KeyValue<K,V>>;
public:
    HashTable(const int& bucketCount);
    ~HashTable();
    int buckets;
    LinkedList<KeyValue<K, V>> * arr{ nullptr };
    void add(const K& key, const V& value);
};// end class HashTable

template<typename K, typename V>
HashTable<K, V>::HashTable(const int& bucketCount) {
    buckets = bucketCount;
    this->arr = new LinkedList<KeyValue<K, V>>[buckets];
}

template <typename K, typename V>
HashTable<K, V>::~HashTable() {
    delete[] arr;
}

template <typename K, typename V>
void HashTable<K, V>::add(const K& key, const V& value) {
    //this is the line of code that breaks
    arr[std::hash<K>{}(key) % buckets].insertLast(new KeyValue<K, V>(key, value));
}
```

This is my linked list class that has the insertLast function

```
//LinkedList class
template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    ~LinkedList();
    void insertLast(const T& value);
    Iterator<T> begin();
    Iterator<T> end();
protected:

    Node<T> *front{ nullptr };
    Node<T> *back{ nullptr };
    int count{ 0 };
};

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList() {
    if (this->front) {
        Node<T> * temp{ this->front->forward };
        while (temp) {
            delete this->front;
            this->front = temp;
            temp = temp->forward;
        }
        delete this->front;
    }
}

//this is the function I'm getting an error on
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::insertLast(const T& value) {
    Node<T> * temp = new Node<T>();
    temp->data = value;
    if (!this->front) {
        // Specific scenario, list is empty
        this->front = temp;
    }
    else {
        // General scenario, at least one node
        this->back->forward = temp;
    }
    this->back = temp;
    this->count++;
}
```

This is my KeyValue class, the table will contain an array of LinkedList with a type of KeyValue

```
//KeyValue class
template <typename K, typename V>
class KeyValue {
public:
    K key{};
    V value{};
    KeyValue();
    KeyValue(const K& key, const V& value);
};

template <typename K, typename V>
KeyValue<K, V>::KeyValue() {

}

template <typename K, typename V>
KeyValue<K, V>::KeyValue(const K& key, const V& value) {
    this->key = key;
    this->value = value;
}
```

Comment: To get a better [mcve], you could have dummied up some parts, such as reducing `KeyValue` to something more like `template <typename K, typename V> class KeyValue {};`. The `LinkedList` methods could be reduced to empty wrappers. Learning how to come up with a minimal example not only helps you get better responses on SO, it can help you uncover the solution on your own, before turning to SO (i.e. get the answer faster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your `LinkedList` variable is defined as

```
LinkedList<KeyValue<K, V>> * arr{ nullptr };
```

inside the `HashTable` class, meaning this is a pointer to a `LinkedList` containing `KeyValues<K, V>`'s

The `insertLast` function is defined as:

```
void insertLast(const T& value);
```

where `T` is the template type of the `LinkedList` class, ie `KeyValue<K, V>` here.

On the other hand you are trying to use the function `insertLast` as

```
arr[std::hash<K>{}(key) % buckets].insertLast(new KeyValue<K, V>(key, value));
```

Here, `new KeyValue<K, V>(key, value)` is a `KeyValue<K, V>*` where the `insertLast` function expects a `const KeyValue<K, V>&`.

If you remove the `new` keyword here it should work as a new object will be created and then copied inside the `insertLast` function.